# I am trying to close one specific chrome tab using command prompt win 10

Tags: command

My goal is to close one specific tab (google chrome) after i have opened more than 1 tab using command prompt on windows 10. So everything should happen automatically since nobody should reach the pc/monitor etc.. I cant just simply use the start "URL" command since its a page which requires a login on the previous page. I have problems explaining why exactly i have to do it this way. I imagine i can use the taskkill command to close a tab. but that requires the Process-ID. The problem for me is that the PID always changes after the tab has been freshly opened. The PC shuts down at 17:00, starts at 08:00 and via autostart 2 tabs are being opened (actually 3 but the first one doesnt matter regarding this problem). The first tab is being opened and then the second one after a delay of 10 seconds (because it wont load until the first page is logged in automatically which takes at least 7 seconds). Now that the second page is open i want to close the first one but i struggle with that. Im doing all of this automatically via command prompt. What also doesnt work is closing chrome with taskkill and reopening the second tab (because of the log-in). I'm definitely no expert (more like a noob) but i would appreciate it if somebody could help me:D.

Comment: You could look into AutoHotKey, and write a macro you can script to do some clicks. You could also write a custom chrome extension for that computer, and use that to add timers that will close a tab based on URL, etc... but that is probably a lot more work.

Comment: mh. Scripting isn't really my strong suit atm (ik stackoverflow is for scripters but i wanted to give it a shot).
Thx for helping though!:)